Problem with permanentRedirect Next.js App router
I use an app router and on each pages, I add
export const dynamic = 'force-static';
I test even without this line and also I have that same case.
The URL page I paste to https://httpstatus.io/ should be redirected to a new page with status 308 -> 200.
Unfortunately, on the first time I get 308 and then 200, but each next time I get only 308. Why?
From API I get information about redirect and I use
permanentRedirect(redirectUrl, RedirectType['push']);
I try comment line with force static and I try revalidate page

Probably, I found solution. I moved logic from server page to middlware and added
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(url, req.url), {
      status: 308,
    });

